# PayPal sandbox: isufficient funds test case

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test PayPal payments. I have created PayPal test accounts, one of them have only 1 USD.

But when I'm trying to buy something with this user - payment is successfull. How do I test case when client have not enough funds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, in sandbox you cannot. I had the same issue, and could not find a solution to it.
If you are using IPN, there is an IPN generator on paypals sandbox where you can generate IPN messages. But that doesn't cover every scenario (for example you cannot generate any recurring payment related IPNs). As far as I know (let me know if I'm wrong) that's the best you can get.